# sending audio file to open ai whisper model

Tags: javascript, blob, filereader, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am converting my recorded audio file to a blob object and then reading it with file reader to make a post request to open ai whisper model
It expects a audio file and model name i.e `whisper-1`

The error i am getting is

`1 validation error for Request\nbody -> file\n  field required (type=value_error.missing)`

my code is below

```
  const handleUpload = () => {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/webm" });

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(audioBlob);

    reader.onload = async () => {
      const audioBase64 = await reader.result.split(",")[1];
      const payload = {
        audio: audioBase64,
        model: "whisper-1",
      };

      const payloadString =  JSON.stringify(payload);

      fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${key}`,
        },
        body: payloadString,
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the `audio file`, pass it to the below function, you'll get the transcription.

It uses `openai's transcription api`.

```
import FormData from "form-data";
import axios from 'axios'

const transcribe = async (file) => {
  let data = new FormData();

  data.append("file", fs.createReadStream(file));
  data.append("model", "whisper-1");
  data.append("language", "en");

  let config = {
    method: "post",
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: "https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions",
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      ...data.getHeaders(),
    },
    data: data,
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.request(config);
    const data = response.data;

    return { data };
  } catch (error) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

I think the problem that you are getting here is:

```
const payload = {
        audio: audioBase64,
        model: "whisper-1",
      };
```

Replace `audio` to `file` as `key` in the `payload object`.
Like this:

```
const payload = {
        file: audioBase64,
        model: "whisper-1",
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

**#Easy solution**

If you are using `multer` to upload the file on `node.js` app and then want to send the audio file to `openAI` [wishper](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text/quickstart?lang=curl) model for transcription you can use below code for it.

First cretae your audio file into `Readable stream` then attach the file name and send in the form-data.

```
  const { default: fetch } = require('node-fetch');
  const FormData = require('form-data');
  const { Readable } = require('stream');

  const transcribe = async (audioFile) => {

  const url = new URL('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions');

  const audioReadStream = Readable.from(audioFile.buffer);

  audioReadStream.path = audioFile.originalname;

  const form = new FormData();

  form.append('file', audioReadStream);
  form.append('model', 'whisper-1');

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${config.openai.api_key}`,
    },
    body: form,
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  if (response.status === 200) {
    return data;
  }
  throw new Error(data.error);
  }
```

Comment: `fetch`, `FormData`, `Blob` and `File` are now part of NodeJS, so you don't need any dependencies. use `new File([buffer], 'audio.mp3', { type: 'audio/mp3'} )` instead.

Comment: yup you are right

Answer (score -1):

https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions - create transcription api takes multipart/form-data.

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  -F file="@/path/to/file/audio.mp3" \
  -F model="whisper-1"
```

either you can use the fs module or send data as form type using form-data